# Returntype of function with input value

Tags: javascript, typescript

So basicly I want to render a returntype for my combined reducers which I do just fine by:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  notes: notesReducer,
  categories: categoriesReducer,
  flyout: flyoutReducer
  // more reducers
});

export type AppState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
```

However if I were to accept a passed in value to the function I am having issues returning the types correctly. Example below:

```
const rootReducer = history =>
  combineReducers({
    router: connectRouter(history),
    page: pageReducer,
    ....
    ....

export type AppState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
```

How can I invoke the function to get the same returned types??

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `ReturnType` twice:

```
const rootReducer = history =>
    combineReducers({
        router: connectRouter(history),
        page: pageReducer,
    });

export type AppState = ReturnType<ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>>;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBKC2AjAlmApgJTQEwK7DQCcIYBeGAHgBUA+AChAC4YqBKMmmO90zkAbgCwAKFCRYABwCGAc0w58RMjABE0uVjwFCKkWOhxw6YFAwhcUJeToALZlLABPHpxUqhwveAOEQIUwrayjbI0CCEjhwiMDGGSKjyWkQQdADe0bGZvhZEzGLGpuaWhLahUOHOADQZmTHqaMz1moqE1cKZAL6sHiJoAB4S4bBQjhJoMACCEhIAylBSlspYULiEYFSjaBTLq+ubFCNjIABmML7+zdo0NB4wQA)